# Android NDK and extern variables in C code

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, extern

I have a library that I want to customize its work (I mean replacing the main of the library by my outside program so I can for example reorder the calls of the library's functions) and for that I had to change some static variable to `extern` variables so the library and my program can handle them both.

My program works fine when on run on my Linux desktop machine, however when I tried to port that to Android using NDK, I couldn't compile it because of the `extern` keyword .

So, I was wondering if there's a way concerning the Android.mk or alternative to the use of `extern` keyword, to make the things work.

Comment: What is the exact error message you're getting, and what does the code it complains about look like?

Comment: I get the "undefined reference" error message

Comment: Could you show your Android.mk file and C source code ?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an "undefined reference" because `extern` is not a variable definition, only a declaration. That means you must have an non-`extern` declation somewhere else in your code, otherwise the compiler doesn't allocate a symbol for your variable.

As for alternatives, no, an `extern` variable is the only way to have a global variable accross multiple object files in C.

If you only need a global variable in the same object file, you can use `static` so the symbol is not exported to other objects.